# Import table data using multiple sql file in psql

Tags: psql, command-line, windows-10, unix, enterprisedb

Local Machine(l1):
Windows 10
psql

Remote Machine(R1):
linux
EDB(postgres)

On my local I have 1000+ sql script containing insert statement . psql is also installed locally .
I need to run this sql script from my local command prompt using psql client .
I can connect to remote db as `psql -h hostnme -U username -p port DBName`  . For single file i know that it can be run like `\i f.sql` . I also tried combining all sql file in one file on windows using command `copy /b *.sql new.sql` . But the new sql file size is 4 GB . Which is not easy to work with . Is there any way I can run those 1000+ sql script from psql without combining from command prompt ?

Comment: Write a loop in something like Powershell and call `psql -f <filename>` 1000 times.

Comment: I am connecting to remote DB with a host, port, username and password .

Comment: The only issue is passing password . How can I avoid passing password 1000 times ?

Comment: Why is that a problem? You can use the `PGPASSWORD` environment variable.